# cross compiling util-linux for ARM, libtool/ld is not taking libs from LDFLAGS path

Tags: linux, arm, cross-compiling, embedded-linux

```
OS_COMP_DIR="/home/dev_team/prebuilt"  
export CROSS_COMPILE="arm-linux-gnueabi"  
export CPPFLAGS=" -I$OS_COMP_DIR/usr/include "  
export LDFLAGS=" -L$OS_COMP_DIR/usr/lib/"  
export AR="/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc-ar-4.9"  
export AS="/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi-as-4.9"  
export LD="/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi-ld-4.9"  
export RANLIB="/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc-ranlib-4.9"  
export CC="/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc-4.9"  
export CPP="/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi-cpp-4.9"  
export CXX="/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi-g++-4.9"  
export NM="/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi-nm"  
cd util-linux-2.28.2
./configure --build=i686-pc-linux-gnu --target=${CROSS_COMPILE} --host=${CROSS_COMPILE}
make V=1
```

Getting the following error when I build, even though all those libraries are in the directory  mentioned in `LDFLAGS`, don't know where ".libs" is coming from

```
arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc-4.9: error: ./.libs/libmount.so: No such file or directory
arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc-4.9: error: /home/dev_team/workspace/util-linux-2.28.2/.libs/libblkid.so: No such file or directory
arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc-4.9: error: /home/dev_team/workspace/util-linux-2.28.2/.libs/libuuid.so:No such file or directory
```

Please help me if anyone knows the solution for this, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have specify `LDFLAGS` right in configure command line :

`./configure --build=i686-pc-linux-gnu --target=${CROSS_COMPILE} --host=${CROSS_COMPILE} LDFLAGS=-L/home/dev_team/prebuilt/usr/lib/ make V=1`

Or you may add to your env:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=" -L$OS_COMP_DIR/usr/lib/"
export LIBRARY_PATH=" -L$OS_COMP_DIR/usr/lib/"
```

Comment: I am still getting the same error, tried both options. I cannot really get why it looks in .libs instead of looking at the given library paths

Comment: Grep LDFLAGS by your configure, or open source and check how you can pass linker options